# Gaussian filter for image bluring

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, gaussianblur, anaconda3

I want to denoise my images with a gaussian filter. I want it to be 5x5 window and sigma=1.4 . I have noticed that the gaussian filter in scipy does not allow you to define the window size. Is there any alternative or did I miss something in scipy library?

Answer (score 0):

You can use open-cv python as an alternative.

```
import cv2
filtered_img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (5, 5), 1.4)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you referring to [`scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter.html), it has a `truncation` parameter. Setting it to 1.4 would most likely truncate the Gaussian of sigma 1.4 to a 5x5 filter.

The documentation doesn’t specify how the filter size is computed, but the usual method is `2*ceil(sigma*truncation)+1`. I have also seen `round` used instead of `ceil`. In either case, 
a truncation of 1.4 would lead to 5.